# gradle equivalent of mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=`pwd`/repo

Tags: maven, gradle

How can I do that? In other words, don't install any dependency anywhere but `pwd`/repo and target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle maintains its own dependency cache (by default under `~/.gradle`), so there is no direct equivalent. Of course it all depends on what exactly you mean by "equivalent" in this context.

Comment: By equivalent, I mean do not store any dependency anywhere but the specified directory.

Comment: Gradle's dependency cache cannot be disabled, but it can be relocated by setting `GRADLE_USER_HOME`. However, it's not the same as a local Maven repository, and you shouldn't interact with it directly.

Comment: AH. I'm leaving out an important detail. I mean when using the maven plugin in gradle, can I have it do what setting maven.repo.local does? I could make a symbolic link to where M2_HOME points and create a conf/settings.xml I guess.... But, something like just settings a property would be great.

Comment: You should be able to do `repositories.mavenLocal().url = "file:///some/path".` Note that the only good reason for using the local Maven repository is to exchange artifacts between Gradle and Maven builds.

Comment: Hmm. Putting that or mavenLocal().set('url', '...') in the repositories clojure thing did not change anything, it seems. But, without setting the property, the gradle cache is updated but not ~/.m2/repository. This is using the webApplication/quickstart sample. So, does it not cache dependencies in maven repositories when using the maven plugin?

Comment: The purpose of the `maven` plugin is to *publish* to Maven repositories. For caching, Gradle will always use its own cache.